# Local host always being added to /etc/hosts.deny when trying to SSH

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, denyhosts

I have a rather odd problem with my server. For some reason the local hostname for my workstation keeps getting added to the `/etc/hosts.deny` and when I try to SSH I get:

> ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

If I use another workstation and delete my hostname from the file, I have a about a 10 second window to login from my workstation before its added again. My workstation is running Mac OSX Mountain Lion and I'm using `ssh` from the Terminal. Any idea what could be up or how to find out what's up?

Comment: You should be able to fix this by adding your hostname to`/etc/hosts.allow`. Are you running any program to modify the hosts.allow/deny files (like denyhosts) ?

Comment: Is the affected machine running OSX (question body) or Linux (tags)? It's probably denyhosts running amok anyway, but please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gilles - this sounds very much like there's a tool running on your computer that monitors the ssh log for failed login attempts, like DenyHosts or Fail2ban. SSH itself won't modify the `/etc/hosts.deny` file.